# wxGrid FreezeTo disable horizontal scrollbar

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wxwidgets, wxgrid

I use wxWidgets 3.1.5  under Windows, in which I have developed a I have a wxGrid that contains more columns than can be displayed, so a horizontal scroll bar is needed.

The problem arises when I use **FreezeTo** in a virtual table base through wxGridTableBase:
if the wxGrid contains **more rows** than can be displayed **both** the horizontal and vertical scroll bars **are visible**,
[image]
otherwise, if all rows are displayed, the vertical scroll bar is not displayed, the horizontal scroll bar it is disabled even though it must be enabled.
[image]

To prove it you can use the example provided by wxWidgets **Grid control wxWidgets sample**, modifying the BigGridFrame constructor in **griddemo.cpp** like so:

```
    // ============================================================================
    // BigGridFrame and BigGridTable:  Sample of a non-standard table
    // ============================================================================

    BigGridFrame::BigGridFrame(long sizeGrid)
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Plugin Virtual Table")
    {
        m_grid = new wxGrid(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
        m_table = new BigGridTable(sizeGrid);

       // VZ: I don't understand why this slows down the display that much,
       //     must profile it...
       //m_table->SetAttrProvider(new MyGridCellAttrProvider);

       m_grid->AssignTable(m_table);

       SetClientSize(FromDIP(wxSize(500, 450)));

       //if sizeGrid <12 the horizontal scrollbar will not be displayed, if sizeGrid> = 12 the horizontal scrollbar will be displayed
       m_grid->FreezeTo(0, 3);
   }
```

If sizeGrid <12 the horizontal scrollbar will not be displayed, if sizeGrid> = 12 the horizontal scrollbar will be displayed

how can i fix this bug?
(See [bug reported on github](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/22602))

Is it possible to solve it with some workaround on my code, instead of intervening on the wxWidgets library ?
For example shrink the height of the wxGrid so that the bottom edge coincides with the last row ? How can I do it ?

Comment: could you try it with 3.1.7 or even with 3.2.0 release candidate `grid` sample? If you still can reproduce it there - open an issue on github.

Comment: @Igor Unfortunately I cannot change the version, the configuration and compilation of 3.1.5 took a long time and too many projects are bound to it

Comment: @Igor I entered a code to be able to find the bug

Comment: you don't have to build you project - just build the library and a `grid` sample. You can also try the sample from the version you have right now and see if the bug is reproducible

Comment: BTW,  this might be a bug in the version you are using, and it could be already fixed in master. Also - I don't understand your comment - in you project you shouldn't be hardworking wx version. You should reference some environment variable or use generic name for directory (wxWidgets instead of wxWidgets-3.1.7).

Comment: See https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/22602

Comment: yes I saw it. You need to wait for the fix.freezing is relatively new feature and it's bound to have bugs...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by applying the patch published to:

[patch](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/c88d18278b182cbd8046d0231fe4db313d772a99)